# Выгрузить данные из TXT в Excel по критерию

Tags: sql, excel

Есть .txt файл, в котором 900 миллионов строк, разбитые по столбцам. 
Из этого файла нужно получить примерно 200к строк и выгрузить их в Excel по идентификатору в одном из столбцов. Как это можно сделать технически? Возможно, что с помощью SQL

Comment: У вас файл с разделителем? Приложите небольшой фрагмент

Comment: Да, там есть разделитель в виде "|". Фрагмент приложить не могу, в данный момент, к сожалению. Но там 5 столбцов и 900 миллионов строк, разделенные "|"

Comment: Если под рукой есть Access - импортируете txt в таблицу, затем выбираете нужные вам данные и экспортируете их в Excel. В любом случаее, более 1 млн строк на лист не сможете загрузить

Comment: 900 *миллионов* строк можете даже не пытаться в эксель выгрузить. Можете хоть примерно оценить количество вытягиваемых строк? если их там реально будет несколько млн или десятков млн, то врядли вы сможете с этим работать в экселе.

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis аксесс неделю будет импортировать столько строк, по моему :) и я что то сомневаюсь, что сделает это по итогу :)

Comment: @teran По необходимому мне столбцу будет примерно около 100-200к строк, 900 млн в сумме, так что в эксель влезет

Comment: @teran ну не знаю. на миллион записей обычно уходит 10-20 секунд (по крайней мере, у меня:)

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis ну мб :) но как-то это уже все равно великоватый объем для аксесса, как мне кажется.

Comment: Если есть возможность файл преобразовать к CSV или TSV (за исключенеим строк с кавычками, это должно быть не очень сложно) - можно задействовать программу [q](http://harelba.github.io/q/index.html) для SQL-запросов к этому файлу. Про быстродействие ничего не скажу :)

Comment: @hitrene есть возможность проверить вариант с Access?

Comment: Вариант использования Python + Pandas (модуль для Python) рассматривается?

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis получится проверить, но позже, ближе к ночи. На самом деле, файл отдан другой команде, они все сделают, но это уже дело принципа. Как только проверю, отпишусь вам

Comment: Сформулируйте чёткий критерий отбора этих 200к строк. Возможно, будет проще и быстрее сделать этот отбор какой-то из утилит командной строки.

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis через Access получилось, причем заняло не так много времени, как я думал изначально. Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если установлен access, то можете попробовать получить данные из файла через Microsoft Access Text Driver:

1. Вкладка "Данные" выбираем "Из других источников" и там "Из Microsoft Query"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Выбираем новый источник данных и задаем имя источника и драйвер

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Нажимаем кнопку "Связь", задаем каталог, где лежит текстовый файл и нажимаем "Параметры>>" и "Определить формат". Там задаем разделить "|", определяем поля и их типы, из скриншота думаю все понятно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4. Создаем запрос, выбираем какие поля включить в запрос

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

5. Настраиваем правила сортировки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

6. Выбираем как вставить данные в таблицу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

7. Получаем результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для примера я сгенерировал файл из случайных данных, 5 целочисленных полей с разделителями "|" из 2.000.000 строк
Выборка по 2 условиям получилась на 500.000 строк по времени на моем компьютере заняло около 10 секунд

Answer (score 2):

Рабочий пример на Python + Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

filename = r'D:\temp\a.csv'
out_excel = r'D:\temp\a.xlsx'

# генерируем случайный CSV (1.000.000 x 3)
pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(10**6,3)), columns=list('abc')) \
  .to_csv(filename, sep='|', index=False)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(out_excel, engine='openpyxl')

i = 0
for df in pd.read_csv(filename, sep='|', chunksize=10**5): 
     # отбираем только те строки где значение столбца `a` == 88
     t = df.query("a == 88")
     t.to_excel(writer, index=False, header=t.columns if i==0 else None, startrow=i)
     i += len(t)

writer.save()
```

Замер скорости для CSV файла содердащего 100.000.000 строк (3 целых числа в каждой строке):

```
In [44]: pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(10**8,3)), columns=list('abc')).to_csv(filename, sep='|', index=False)

In [45]: %%timeit -n 1 -r 1
    ...: writer = pd.ExcelWriter(out_excel, engine='openpyxl')
    ...:
    ...: i = 0
    ...: for df in pd.read_csv(filename, sep='|', chunksize=10**5):
    ...:      t = df.query("a == 88")
    ...:      t.to_excel(writer, index=False, header=t.columns if i==0 else None, startrow=i)
    ...:      i += len(t)
    ...:
    ...: writer.save()
    ...:
1min 59s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
```

**Итог**: для целочисленных данных (100.000.000 строк) это занимает примерно 2 минуты на моем стареньком ноутбуке...

Answer (score -3):

> 900 миллионов строк, разбитые по столбцам. Эти данные нужно вытянуть в Excel

[Эксель столько не съест](https://support.office.com/ru-ru/article/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-Microsoft-Excel-1672B34D-7043-467E-8E27-269D656771C3):

> Общее количество строк и столбцов на листе: 1 048 576 строк и 16 384
>   столбца

Comment: а никто ему и не собирается скормить все строки

Comment: @teran это твои фантазии. В вопросе есть цифра 900 млн и ни про какие  разбивки на 900 файлов нет ни слова. А если бы было - ничего делать не нужно - в экселе можно задать разделитель. .

Comment: @SeVlad в комментах уже указано, что нужно получить 200к строк

Comment: Да, прошу прощения, что запутал. Из этих 900 млн нужно по одному столбцу выгрузить строки. Их выйдет тысяч 200

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis ок. увидел, но тем не менее в вопросе чётко сказано "эти данные". Все 900 млн. А коммменты - то такое.. сегодня есть - завтра нет. Но и даже если так - чтобы запихнуть 200тыщ из 900 млн -  нужно вначале где-то сделать выборку. А это уже совсем другой вопрос.

Comment: @SeVlad *в вопросе чётко сказано "эти данные"* О_О ихде? в вопросе всё чётко - сначала отобрать, потом что получилось загрузить.

Comment: @Akina, особо одарённым посвящается: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/758333/revisions